# How To find Out if Element is Wrapped by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i find out if an Object is Wrapped by jQuery.

```
var obj = $('div');

if(obj is a jQuery wrapped object)
{
   then do something
}
```

I am quite new in the Javascript World.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what would be the use of this?

Comment: well... it would tell you if the variable you're looking at is a jQuery object... i thought that was self-evident..? one tip which i picked up was to always prefix my variables which were jQuery objects with a $ (eg: `var $obj = $('div');`). This really helps you remember what you're working with.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var isJQuery = obj instanceof jQuery;  // or obj instanceof $;
```

Comment: If it helps the OP, $ is simply an alias to the jQuery function. For this reason "obj instanceof $" would also work.

Answer (score 2):

You can test like this:

```
if(obj instanceof jQuery) {
    // ...
}
```

However, it's not entirely correct to say that the HTML element is "wrapped" in a jQuery object, rather the jQuery object is a collection of zero or more HTML elements. So, if you really want to be careful you could test first whether it contains any elements at all, as follows:

```
if(obj instanceof jQuery && obj.length > 0) {
    var element = obj[0];
    // do something with element
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. A jquery object might "wrap" no HTML elements at all. As `obj.size()` is now deprecated, you'll have to use `obj.length` though.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (obj.jquery) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

That's the simplest way. Checking the object's constructor is another option but note that it won't work across global contexts (e.g. between a parent page and a frame).

Answer (score 0):

This check can help distinguish an array object from a jQuery "array-like" object if the "element" var is one or the other.

```
if (jQuery.isArray(element)) {
    // plain array object: []
} else {
    // jQuery wrapped object
}
```

From jQuery docs:

$.isArray() returns a Boolean indicating whether the object is a JavaScript array (not an array-like object, such as a jQuery object).

Answer (score -2):

Not a jQuery user, this is untested, etc. but

```
if (!(obj instanceof Element))
{
  // ...
}
```

may work, unless jQuery does weird things in its wrapping.  Of course this does require you to know that obj can never be a non-jQuery, non-DOM element, but hopefully that's not hard to enforce.